Type inference for Nitro plugin
In my Nuxt3 application I would like to use drizzle as my ORM. I registered the DB connection as a Nitro plugin like this:
export default defineNitroPlugin(async (nitroApp) => {
  const db = drizzle(new Database('sqlite.db'), { schema: { ...schemas } });
  migrate(db, { migrationsFolder: 'server/database/migrations' });

  nitroApp.hooks.hook('request', (event) => {
    event.context.$database = db;
  });
});

With this I can use the DB in my API calls but the problem is that i have no type inference here. When I use the database in my requests the type of it is any. First of all I'm not sure how to set the type here. Second I'm not even sure what exact type I should use here as the Drizzle object is highly generic. I would like to use type inference here but I'm not sure if that's possible here or how I can achieve this

You need to specifically tell Drizzle/nuxt what the schemas look like, as the Nitro plugin is obfuscating the types when making them globally accessible.
First make sure to move out the db constant and export it so that we can access it when augmenting the types:
export const db = drizzle(new Database('sqlite.db'), { schema: { ...schemas } });

... rest of your Nitro definition

Create a types.d.ts where you augment the database variable to be the type of the database
import { db } from './path/to/db';
import { H3EventContext } from 'h3';

declare module 'h3' {
  interface H3EventContext {
    $database: typeof db;
  }
}

I haven't tested the code personally, but it should be in the vicinity of what is needed.
Good luck!
